# Reciving 404 network Error while refreshing gatsby website

Tags: azure, azure-storage, gatsby, hosting, azure-storage-account

My Gatsby application is hosted in an Azure storage account. While I'm accessing the site for the first time it does not show a 404 but after a refresh, it shows a 404 error. The issues are not able to recreate in the local environment and in the gatsby cloud server. [image: 404 Error on URL path]

Comment: Please check out this [reference](https://support.gatsbyjs.com/hc/en-us/articles/360056267354-Deploying-to-Azure-Storage) try to Setting Up the Hosting Integration

Comment: @Imrankhan-MT I have use that documentation for the setup

Answer (score 0):

The issues have been resolved by adding a new rule in the Azure CDN rules engine.
please refer to this documentation https://antbutcher.medium.com/hosting-a-react-js-app-on-azure-blob-storage-azure-cdn-for-ssl-and-routing-8fdf4a48feeb.